# Let $x$ be an irrational number. Prove that there exist infinitely many rational numbers $\dfrac pq$ that satisfy the following

Tags: combinatorics

$$\bigg|\,x-\dfrac pq\,\bigg|<\dfrac 1{q^2+q}$$

My idea would be to solve the inequality for $\frac pq$ and then somehow use the pigeonhole principle.  Is this heading in the right direction? Any hints would be helpful!

Comment: Actually, that's a good idea. Look up Dirichlet's approximation theorem - it was proved using the pigeon-hole principle.

Answer (score 5):

The key here
is continued fractions.
Look them up.

An irrational number
has an infinite number
of convergents to its continued fraction.
Each of then satisfies
$|x-\frac{p_n}{q_n}|
< \frac1{q_n q_{n+1}}
$.
Since
$q_{n+1}
> q_n
$,
this proves your
statement.

Comment: in *Diophantine Approximations,* Niven does the Hurwitz $\sqrt 5 \; q^2$ result with no continued fractions, page 6.

Comment: I seem to recall reading a proof many years ago that at least one of every three consecutive convergents satisfies this. And then, trying to improve the $\sqrt{5}$ but for fewer convergents, things get complicated.

Comment: page 31 in Khinchin's little book, Theorem 20. He then emphasizes that the Golden Ratio satisfies the inequality only finitely many times if $\sqrt 5$ is replaced by anything larger. I do not see that Khinchin includes https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thue%E2%80%93Siegel%E2%80%93Roth_theorem

Answer (score 1):

Here is the standard argument, perhaps what you had in mind.

HINT:
Let $Q\ge 1$ integer and consider the $Q$ fractional parts $\{a x\}$ for $1\le a \le Q$. Either one of them is closer to $0$ or $1$ by less than $\frac{1}{Q+1}$, or two of them are closer by less than $\frac{1}{Q+1}$ ( think of the $Q$ points $\frac{1}{Q+1}$, $\frac{2}{Q+1}$, $\ldots$, $\frac{Q}{Q+1}$ in $[0,1]$). From here one concludes that there exists integers $c$ and $1 \le d \le Q$ so that $|d x - c| < \frac{1}{Q+1}$.